# Screen tearing fix disables laptop monitor on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I am trying to fix screen tearing on ubuntu 20.04 using Nvidia drivers(440), Normally I run a dual-screen setup with my laptop and an external screen. I found a fix that works, forcing composition pipeline in x-server settings, but when I do that my laptop screen is no longer recognized. I fixed this by deleting the xorg.conf file, but I am back to screen tearing issues. I would like to know if there is way I can fix screen tearing while keeping my dual-screen setup. I tried pasting the Xorg.conf, but as it turns out I don't have one right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: upon further inspection, the laptop screen does show up on nvidia settings once I force composition pipeline but it still doesn't show up in ubuntu settings, and i can't find out how to configure it to be dual screen

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the exactly same situation for days. And this is my solution which works for me.The `force composition pipeline` option does work for solving tearing issues, but according to [this archlinux troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing), on the 'multi-monitor' section, it points out that if you just set the `force composition pipeline` for only one monitor, it will make the driver disables the other monitor, so we should turn on this option for all your monitors at the same time. Here is my setting example (assume that both of your monitors are working and one of them is tearing):

- First of all, run `xrandr` in terminal, to check the monitor situations

```bsh
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00 +  60.00* 
   1680x1050    144.00  
   1280x1024    144.00  
   1440x900     144.00  
   1280x800     144.00  
   1280x720     144.00  
   1024x768     144.00  
   800x600      144.00  
   640x480      144.00
```

it shows that I got 2 monitors: DP-2 & eDP-1-0, and their relative positions are giving as well like this `1920x1080+1920+0 & 1920x1080+0+0`.

- Then run this in terminal to turn on `force composition pipeline` option for both monitors

```bsh
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-2: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On}, eDP-1-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On}"
```

Okay, it will work immediately without reboot. But I have no idea about making it permanent, I'm wondering if I can write a shell file and run it after every boot. Maybe you guys have a better solution, please show us!

--------------EDITED-------------------------

I made that command an alia in `.zshrc` and run the alia on every boot up.